# How to unit test .Include for Entity Framework eager loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a method whose purpose is to get an Entity from a `DbSet` with relevant data already eagerly loaded into it (it has a sequence in `.Includes` in its logic). The relevant fields are `virtual IEnumerable` and are lazily loaded.

Now I want to unit-test this method to check if it loads all the data I need. I don't know how to get around to it, I can create an expected entity and fill it up with data, but simply mocking a `IDbSet` (I'm using Moq) doesn't work - if I remove all the `.Includes` from the tested method it will still return all the related entities, which is not the "live" behavior it'd have on an actual database (the entities would not be loaded and the method's contract would be unfulfilled).

So, how do I mock the `IDbSet`so it actually lazy-loads without explicit `.Includes`? Or maybe I'm doing this completely wrong and there's some other way to test this method?

Comment: Short Answer: You can't. Suggestion: Do an integration test.

Comment: .Include has been unit tested for you :)

Comment: *If* you would be able to mock it, the only thing your unit test would prove is that the mocking code works.

Comment: I don't want to test `.Include`, but rather the method's contract stating "I do call `.Include` for everything that needs to be included."

Comment: Why was this being downvoted? I see no reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing something like whether your service/repository is including related entities would be an integration test scenario rather than a unit test. An integration test like this looks like a unit test, and is written with NUnit/MSTest but would be one that is separated off from the unit tests so that it isn't run with the normal unit test suite as these can be rather time consuming to run.

For instance.

```
MyParentEntity entity = null;
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(connectionString))
{
    var myRepository = new MyRepository(dbContext);
    entity = myRepository.GetEntityById(1);
} // leave the scope of the DbContext.

// example asserts...
Assert.IsNotNull(entity.Relative, "Relative was not eager loaded."); // Null or EF Exception if proxy attempts to lazy-load.
Assert.IsTrue(entity.Children.Count == 3, "Children were not eager loaded.");
```

This implies a known data state, so integration tests commonly use in-memory DBs that can be populated reasonably quickly, or are set up to restore DB backups for a known data state on test fixture setup.

Comment: If you uses in-memory database, then it will not be time consuming anymore and can be considered as unit test ;)

Comment: At the start, yeah, though as systems grow the # of scenarios lead to larger data footprints to cover larger sets of those scenarios, or juggling a lot of different databases with subsets of data. It's do-able, though unit tests are geared to testing business behaviour and designed to run as fast as possible given they will be run very frequently when using TDD. Hence I mock the repositories for unit tests to return composed entity classes leaving EF behaviour to more holistic integration tests.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to close the context, You could do something like

```
_context.Entry(retreivedEntry).Reference(e => e.Field).IsLoaded
_context.Entry(retreivedEntry).Collection(e => e.CollectionField).IsLoaded
```

Comment: The question is not how to test that related data is loaded, but how to make a distinction between data having been loaded eagerly or lazily. It's impossible to test that. They'd have to inspect the generated SQL statements.